# Button click showing same data in angular2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-table, ngfor, angular-components

I have tried to populate a bootstrap `modal` with the details of respective rows in a table. Modal is showing fine but it is **getting populated with** only the **first rows data** on click of any of the buttons.

Here's a link:https://plnkr.co/edit/3tl6S9CuGCv8VxXsOq7Y?p=preview

What I have done is `property binded` the `data` value in component's `pass` @Input decorator as you can in the below code(Please refer to plunker in order to know more about the components):

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>
  <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor='let data of datas'>
        <td>{{data.name}}</td>
        <td>{{data.age}}</td>
        <td>{{data.email}}</td>
        <td><detail-emp [pass]='data'></detail-emp></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Now what I beleive is that when I pass individual `data` from `datas` in `*ngFor` to its component, **respective row data should be passed**. But it isn't the case. The modal on click of any modal button shows only the first rows data.

How can I make sure that only the data from the clicked row is shown in the modal and not always the first row's data.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" [attr.data-target]="'#exampleModal_' + pass.id ">
  Show Data
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal_{{pass.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Employee Detail</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Name : {{pass.name}}</p>
        <p>Age : {{pass.age}}</p>
        <p>Email : {{pass.email}}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the problem is in your ids of button and modal ..you need to SET A DIFFERENT ID (exampleModal_{{pass.id}})  FOR EACH MODAL IN EACH ROW .. AND THEN ATTACH THE BUTTON OF EACH GENERATED ID ([attr.data-target]="'#exampleModal_' + pass.id ")
.. you were open always the same modal ..hope it helps

Comment: Works quite good. But how did it work? I also saw before that it was showing just the first row's id on any button's click.

Comment: cause if you don't set different ids for each modal of each row .. the buttons always open only the modal with id="exampleModal"